# The target entry-point "ng-network-status" has missing dependencies: - rxjs/Rx

Tags: angular, rxjs, version, angular12

I have upgraded angular project from 7 to 12 now it is giving me below issue while doing ng serve

```
 Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...D:\Projects\CCM_Dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40
                throw new Error("The target entry-point \"" + invalidTarget.entryPoint.name + "\" has missing dependencies:\n" +
                ^

Error: The target entry-point "ng-network-status" has missing dependencies:
 - rxjs/Rx

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (D:\Projects\CCM_Dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
```

My package.json is

```json
{
   "dependencies":{
      "@agm/core":"^1.0.0-beta.5",
      "@angular/animations":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/cdk":"^7.3.6",
      "@angular/common":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/compiler":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/core":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/forms":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/http":"6.1.10",
      "@angular/material":"^6.4.7",
      "@angular/platform-browser":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"12.2.16",
      "@angular/router":"12.2.16",
      "@coreui/angular":"^2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@coreui/coreui":"^2.1.16",
      "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips":"^1.2.0",
      "@coreui/icons":"^0.3.0",
      "@material/checkbox":"^2.1.1",
      "@material/form-field":"^2.1.1",
      "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap":"^4.1.3",
      "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids":"^17.3.29",
      "angular-2-daterangepicker":"^1.1.52",
      "angular-calendar":"^0.25.2",
      "angular2-chartjs":"^0.5.1",
      "angular2-csv":"^0.2.9",
      "angular2-datatable":"^0.6.0",
      "angular2-fullcalendar":"^1.0.19",
      "angularx-flatpickr":"^6.0.0",
      "bootstrap":"^4.3.1",
      "chart.js":"^2.9.3",
      "chartjs-funnel":"^1.0.5",
      "chartjs-plugin-stacked100":"^0.4.6",
      "core-js":"^2.5.7",
      "crypto-js":"^4.1.1",
      "file-saver":"^1.3.8",
      "flag-icon-css":"^3.0.0",
      "flatpickr":"^4.5.1",
      "font-awesome":"^4.7.0",
      "hammerjs":"^2.0.8",
      "jspdf":"^1.4.1",
      "moment":"^2.23.0",
      "mutationobserver-shim":"^0.3.2",
      "mydatepicker":"^2.6.4",
      "ng-multiselect-dropdown":"^0.3.8",
      "ng-network-status":"^0.2.3",
      "ng-pick-datetime":"^6.0.16",
      "ng2-charts":"^1.6.0",
      "ng2-pdf-viewer":"^5.1.2",
      "ngx-bootstrap":"^3.0.1",
      "ngx-daterangepicker-material":"^1.3.4",
      "ngx-drag-scroll":"^2.0.0-beta.3",
      "ngx-mask":"^9.0.2",
      "ngx-perfect-scrollbar":"^6.2.0",
      "ngx-spinner":"^6.1.2",
      "pdfjs-dist":"^2.0.489",
      "primeicons":"^1.0.0",
      "primeng":"^6.1.7",
      "rxjs":"^7.5.5",
      "rxjs-compat":"^6.6.7",
      "serial-number":"^1.3.0",
      "shallow-render":"^8.5.2",
      "simple-line-icons":"^2.4.1",
      "ts-helpers":"^1.1.2",
      "ts-md5":"^1.2.11",
      "xlsx":"^0.13.5",
      "zone.js":"^0.11.6"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular":"^12.2.17",
      "@angular/cli":"^12.2.17",
      "@angular/compiler-cli":"^12.2.16",
      "@angular/language-service":"^12.2.16",
      "@types/jasmine":"^2.8.8",
      "@types/jasminewd2":"^2.0.3",
      "@types/node":"^10.3.4",
      "codelyzer":"^4.4.2",
      "jasmine-core":"^3.1.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter":"^4.2.1",
      "karma":"^6.4.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher":"^2.2.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter":"^2.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine":"^1.1.2",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter":"^1.2.0",
      "protractor":"^7.0.0",
      "ts-node":"^6.1.1",
      "tslint":"^6.1.3",
      "typescript":"^4.3.5"
   },
   "engines":{
      "node":">= 12.22.12",
      "npm":">= 6.14.16"
   }
}
```

I have also tried reinstalling `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat`. Please let me know how can I solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: u must remove rxjs-compat aftermigrate to v8 as i know, and material with cdk must be same version 12.2.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use interactive upgrade guide: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=7.2-12.0

First off, probably all Angular related packages should start with version `12`, fix that. Upgrade other deps https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version. For completeness sake, also do `npm i rxjs-compat`.